# Simulated annealing doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement n-queens problems using `simulated annealing`. I have looked up at all the existing problems and it doesn't solve my problem. The code that I have come up with is this

```
#Generate random state for Simulated Annealing
def generateRandomState(n):
    rand = [0] * n
    for num in range(0, n):
        pos = random.randint(0, n-1)
        rand[num] = pos
    return rand

#Cost function for Simulated Annealing
def costFunction(solution):
    cost = 0
    for position in range(0, len(solution)):
        for next_position in range(position+1, len(solution)):
            if (solution[position] == solution[next_position]) or abs(position - next_position) == abs(solution[position] - solution[next_position]):
            cost = cost + 1
    return cost

def generateNextState(state):
    for i in range(0, len(state)):
        state[i] = random.randint(0,len(state)-1)
    return state

def simulatedAnnealing(solution, temperature, alpha):
    max_iter = 170000
    size= len(solution)
    current_state = generateRandomState(size)

    for iteration in range(max_iter):
        temperature = temperature * alpha

        next_state = generateNextState(current_state)
        delta_E = costFunction(next_state) - costFunction(current_state)
        exp = decimal.Decimal(decimal.Decimal(math.e) ** (decimal.Decimal(-delta_E) * decimal.Decimal(temperature)))
        if (delta_E>0) or (exp > random.uniform(0,1)):
           current_state = next_state[:]

        if(costFunction(current_state) == 0):
           return current_state
```

I know that my individual modules like `costFunction` are working correctly. However the solution is not being generated. My code is based on this [link](https://github.com/Goktug/8queens-simulated-annealing-python/blob/master/simulated-annealing.py). When I run my code for `n=4` all the iterations get over and no solution is generated.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. To start with, your `generateNextState` function is fundamentally broken. It has both design and implementation issues.

Lets handle the implementation issue first. The function modifies `state` in place, before *also* returning it. That's not good since you're passing the current state in, and then later comparing the new state with the old one (which is not very useful if they're the same object). The function should probably make a copy of the input.

The design issue is that it creates a new state that is completely random. The new state has no relation to the previous state. That's bad since it means your search is just picking values at random and seeing if you eventually guess a solution. You should pick a new state that is closely related to the old state. For instance, you could try moving a random queen to a random row:

```
def generateNextState(state):
    new_state = state[:] # copy the state, so we don't modify the original
    new_state[random.randint(0, len(state)-1)] = random.randint(0,len(state)-1)
    return new_state
```

There are lots of other ways to generate the new states, this is just one idea that came to my mind. Other options might be to move some or all of the queens to a neighboring position. Or, if you created your initial state from a `range` (so each value is present exactly once), you could swap the rows between two columns, generating a random permutation. That approach may be more efficient, since the state space of permutations is smaller than a state space that allows repeated values.

The other issues have to do with how you pick whether or not to use the new state you've generated. Your current logic has a bunch of stuff backwards. I think you want to change these lines:

```
    exp = decimal.Decimal(decimal.Decimal(math.e) ** (decimal.Decimal(-delta_E) * decimal.Decimal(temperature)))
    if (delta_E>0) or (exp > random.uniform(0,1)):
```

To something more like this:

```
    exp = math.exp(-delta_E / temperature)       # divide by temp, no need for decimals
    if delta_E < 0 or exp > random.uniform(0,1): # first condition needs the operator flipped
```

Here's the full version of the code I've been playing with. I've changed some more things that aren't necessary for working code, but they make diagnosing issues easier:

```
import random
import math

#Generate random state for Simulated Annealing
def generateRandomState(n):
    return list(range(n)) # in python 2 you don't need the `list` call here

#Cost function for Simulated Annealing
def costFunction(solution):
    cost = 0
    for position in range(0, len(solution)):
        for next_position in range(position+1, len(solution)):
            if (solution[position] == solution[next_position]) or abs(position - next_position) == abs(solution[position] - solution[next_position]):
                cost = cost + 1
    return cost

def generateNextState(state): # randomly swap two values
    state = state[:]
    i, j = random.sample(range(len(state)), 2)
    state[i], state[j] = state[j], state[i]
    return state

def simulatedAnnealing(size, temperature, alpha):
    max_iter = 170000
    current_state = generateRandomState(size)
    current_cost = costFunction(current_state)

    for iteration in range(max_iter):
        print(current_state, current_cost, temperature)
        temperature = temperature * alpha

        next_state = generateNextState(current_state)
        next_cost = costFunction(next_state)
        delta_E = next_cost - current_cost
        if delta_E<0 or math.exp(-delta_E / temperature) > random.uniform(0,1):
           current_state = next_state
           current_cost = next_cost
           if current_cost == 0:
              return current_state

    return None
```

An example run:

```
In [342]: simulatedAnnealing(8, 2, 0.99)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 28 2
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7] 18 1.98
[6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 7] 8 1.9602
[6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0, 7] 5 1.9405979999999998
[6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 7] 4 1.92119202
[6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 7] 4 1.9019800997999998
[3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 0, 7] 4 1.8829602988019998
[3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 0, 7] 4 1.8641306958139798
[6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 7] 4 1.84548938885584
[6, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7] 4 1.8270344949672814
[6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 7] 5 1.8087641500176086
[6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 7] 5 1.7906765085174325
[6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 7] 5 1.7727697434322582
[6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 0] 6 1.7550420459979357
[6, 7, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0] 5 1.7374916255379562
[3, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0] 5 1.7201167092825767
[3, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0] 5 1.7029155421897508
[3, 7, 0, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6] 3 1.6858863867678533
[3, 7, 0, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6] 3 1.6690275229001748
[3, 5, 0, 1, 7, 2, 4, 6] 4 1.652337247671173
[3, 5, 0, 1, 7, 2, 4, 6] 4 1.6358138751944613
[1, 5, 0, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6] 2 1.6194557364425166
[1, 5, 0, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6] 2 1.6032611790780915
[1, 5, 0, 3, 7, 4, 2, 6] 2 1.5872285672873105
[1, 5, 0, 3, 7, 4, 2, 6] 2 1.5713562816144375
[1, 5, 0, 2, 7, 4, 3, 6] 4 1.555642718798293
[1, 5, 0, 2, 7, 4, 3, 6] 4 1.5400862916103102
[1, 5, 2, 0, 7, 4, 3, 6] 3 1.524685428694207
[4, 5, 2, 0, 7, 1, 3, 6] 4 1.509438574407265
[4, 5, 2, 0, 7, 1, 3, 6] 4 1.4943441886631923
[7, 5, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 6] 3 1.4794007467765604
[7, 5, 2, 0, 4, 6, 3, 1] 3 1.4646067393087947
[7, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 1] 3 1.4499606719157068
[7, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 1] 3 1.4354610651965496
[7, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 1] 3 1.4211064545445842
[7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 1] 1 1.4068953899991383
[7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 1] 1 1.392826436099147
[7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 1] 1 1.3788981717381554
[7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 1] 1 1.365109190020774
[6, 5, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 1] 1 1.3514580981205662
[6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 5] 1 1.3379435171393605
[6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 5] 1 1.324564081967967
[6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 5] 1 1.3113184411482872
[6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 5] 1 1.2982052567368043
[4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 0, 3, 5] 4 1.2852232041694363
[3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 0, 4, 5] 5 1.2723709721277419
[3, 1, 2, 6, 0, 7, 4, 5] 5 1.2596472624064645
[3, 1, 2, 5, 0, 7, 4, 6] 3 1.2470507897824
[3, 1, 2, 5, 0, 7, 4, 6] 3 1.234580281884576
[3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 7, 2, 6] 5 1.2222344790657302
[3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0, 2, 6] 3 1.210012134275073
[3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 6] 4 1.1979120129323222
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 6] 7 1.1859328928029989
[2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3] 5 1.1740735638749689
[2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3] 5 1.162332828236219
[2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3] 5 1.150709499953857
[4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3] 3 1.1392024049543183
[4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 0, 7, 3] 2 1.1278103809047753
[4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 0, 7, 3] 2 1.1165322770957276
[0, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 3] 1 1.1053669543247702
[0, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3] 3 1.0943132847815225
[0, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3] 3 1.0833701519337071
[0, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 1, 3] 3 1.07253645041437
[6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3] 3 1.0618110859102263
[1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 0, 6, 3] 3 1.051192975051124
[1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 0, 3] 3 1.0406810453006128
[6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 1, 0, 3] 5 1.0302742348476066
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 1.0199714924991305
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 1.0097717775741393
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 0.9996740597983979
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 0.9896773192004139
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 0.9797805460084098
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 0, 3] 2 0.9699827405483257
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 0] 2 0.9602829131428424
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 0] 2 0.950680084011414
[6, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 0] 2 0.9411732831712999
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.9317615503395869
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.922443934836191
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.9132194954878291
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.9040873005329508
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8950464275276213
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8860959632523451
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8772350036198217
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8684626535836234
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8597780270477872
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8511802467773093
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8426684443095362
[6, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8342417598664409
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0] 1 0.8258993422677765
[6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 0] 1 0.8176403488450987
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1] 1 0.8094639453566478
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] 1 0.8013693059030813
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] 1 0.7933556128440505
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] 1 0.78542205671561
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] 1 0.7775678361484539
[6, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] 1 0.7697921577869694
Out[342]: [4, 0, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 2]
```

Comment: The second suggestion that you gave `exp = math.exp(-delta_E / temperature)` gave me `OverflowError: math range error`.

Comment: Are you using a really high starting temperature? That formula is intended for temperatures that start around 1 (maybe 10 would work too, but it'd be mostly a random walk at the start).

Comment: In that code link that I gave in my question, the temperature used was `4000`. I brought it down to `100` but still the same error

Comment: What are you using for `alpha`? It should be some value close to, but smaller than 1 so that the temperature gradually decays.

Comment: Yes I am taking alpha to be 0.9

Comment: Well, I'm stumped by the overflow then. I can't reproduce it in my code, so perhaps you should add some diagnostics in your version to see if there's something strange going on (like enormous cost values or something).

Comment: The strange thing is if I add the decimal then it doesn't give the overflow error. Thanks for the help man

Comment: I accepted your answer. Its working with the decimal but if I put large value of n it doesnt give any solution even for n=10. Any advice on that?

Comment: No idea. Simulated Annealing isn't guaranteed to find a solution, so maybe you're just unlucky? I've been able to find solutions pretty quickly for every board size I've tried. Using a unique list of values for the start state (e.g. `range(n)`), and randomly swapping two values to get the next state makes it a bit faster, but I did have one run that failed (with I think n=6) when it got stuck in a group of connected local minimum cost values. It might be better if it sometimes swapped more than two values at a time.

Comment: Could you like edit your answer just to include how hou are generating the next state?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include my full code. I've also used the `generateNextState` method I'd suggested in the earlier code block and it worked too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Really appreciate the help